# How to permanently enable the hs-minor-mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using thhs code in the .emacs file to permanently enable the hs-minor-mode and to change the shortcut:

```
(setq-default hs-minor-mode t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-h") (kbd "C-c @ C-h"))         ;;hiding block of code
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-r") (kbd "C-c @ C-s"))         ;;revealing block of code
```

But the mode is not activated automatically. what should i do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want it to be truly global, this does the trick:

```
(define-globalized-minor-mode global-hs-minor-mode
  hs-minor-mode hs-minor-mode)

(global-hs-minor-mode 1)
```

Comment: Doesnt work for me. Emacs 24. Praveen's answer worked.

Comment: I've tried http://stackoverflow.com/users/1123/magnar 's answer on Emacs 24.4.91.1, and found some buffer rejected to enable hs-minor-mode, because hs-minor-mode parse buffer to check availability.  In my case, I could activate successfully with `(defun my_hideshow-ignore-setup-failure() (ignore-errors (hs-minor-mode)))
(define-globalized-minor-mode global-hs-minor-mode
  hs-minor-mode my_hideshow-ignore-setup-failure)
`

Answer (score 35):

You can turn on `hs-minor-mode` for a specific mode like C, C++ mode using `c-mode-common-hook`.

```lisp
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook #'hs-minor-mode)
```

In Emacs 24 or later, you can turn it on in all programming modes using `prog-mode-hook`.

```lisp
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'hs-minor-mode)
```

Comment: Still not working for some reason.I added the second code. I still have to switch on the hs-minor-mode.

Comment: Before manually turning on, can you check the value of `prog-mode-hook` using `C-h v` (`describe-variable`) to see if what you have added is effective?

Comment: Two comments: `(lambda () (hs-minor-mode))` is better written `#'hs-minor-mode`.  And `prog-mode-hook` is new in Emacs-24 so if you use an older Emacs, changing that hook won't have any effect.

Comment: (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'hs-minor-mode) works for me. I'm running Emacs 24.3.1

Comment: To add on to this I found it very helpful to bind toggle code block hiding to an easily used key (one of the function keys for example.  Here is what i used in my .emacs file:
`(global-set-key (kbd "<f1>") 'hs-toggle-hiding)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable it everywhere, and start the buffer with the code folded by hs-hide-all, do

```
(defun my-hide-all()
  (interactive)
  (hs-minor-mode)
  (hs-hide-all))
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'my-hide-all)
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this will cause hs-minor-mode to try and turn on in modes that don't like it. Like fundamental, or minibuffer, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the previous answers, but the one below works best for me.

```
(add-hook 'vhdl-mode-hook #'vhdl-hs-minor-mode)
```